# MySQL Search Refinement (replace long regex with subquery)

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query

```
select query from HR_Health_Logs where query REGEXP 'CPU|MAC|PC|abacus|calculator|laptop|mainframe|microcomputer|minicomputer|machine';
```

Except that the regex is much longer, and contains many synonyms and misspellings.

I need to cut this short and have a table with all the synonyms and misspellings, so that I can avoid this very long query. So I'm looking for something like

```
select query from HR_Health_Logs where query REGEXP '**HAVE A TABLE WITH ALL MY SYNONYMS AND MISSPELLINGS SEARCHED HERE**';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  query
FROM    HR_Health_Logs l, synonym s
WHERE   l.query = s.synonym
```

Answer (score 3):

How about the [`ANY` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html) ?

```
select query from HR_Health_Logs where query REGEXP ANY (SELECT spell FROM misspelled WHERE correct = 'masturbate' ) ;
```

Comment: got a problem with this > why does this come in ? WHERE correct = 'masturbate' , basically any word [syn + misp] are all correct- so i need to only run through all

Comment: My query was specificly designed to search for all HR_Health_Logs.query that contined 'masturbation' synonyms, because I (incorrectly) thought that was your need. Now if you just want all the matches of all the synonyms, just remove the WHERE clause in the subquery... Also I named it misspelled, but that could be synonyms.

Comment: Jst a Quick one > What Engine are you using to test this ?

Comment: InnoDB, but I think this would work with MyIsam as well. But if you don't need REGEXP, you shouldn't use it, since it's far slower than simple equality.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT query
FROM HR_Health_Logs
WHERE query IN (
  SELECT synonym AS query
  FROM synonyms_table
  WHERE word = 'masturbation'
  UNION
  SELECT misspelling AS query
  FROM misspellings_table
  WHERE word = 'masturbation'
)
```

Assuming your synonyms and misspellings are in two separate tables. Otherwise you'll only use one of the subqueries and drop the UNION.